# How to find the legal, yet best priced authorized visa on arrival approval letter agency for Vietnam tourist visa

Tags: tourist-visas, vietnam

To visit Vietnam as a tourist, some must successfully apply for a *Visa On Arrival* (**VOA**) *approval letter* and carry such approval letter **printed**, both when arriving to *departure airport* and a *destination airport* (international airport) in Vietnam.

To try to get such approval letter, one has to visit a website of one of the Vietnamese government *Authorized Visa on Arival Approval Letter Agency* (**AVoAALA**), fill in a form and pay a fee;
For one month VOA approval letter, issuing fee will be about 18 USD.

If the try was successful, after about 5 days (or less, if an additional fee payed), an approval letter will be sent to the email given in in the form.

- When reaching to a departure airport, checking-in in the flight company's counter must be done with this approval letter (their worker might not care if it is printed or from smartphone app but a Vietnamese border officer probably will).
- After I landed on Vietnam, I went tot the VOA office and filled in a required form, I then gave that form, the printed approval letter and my passport to a Vietnamese border officer which examined all of these and then demanded me 15 USD or 25 USD (I don't recall exactly) *stamping fee* for stamping the visa that should be prepared in a few minutes after payment;
  I payed and waited for the preparation of the visa and later when my passport was returned to me with that visa, I could enter Vietnam via border police counter.

### My problem

I understand that there are many AVoAALA and each one can charge different prices (either per month of stay and/or other reasons).

To work simple and fast I chose the AVoAALA recommended by the Vietnamese embassy of the country that a citizenship of which I currently hold, but I recognize no must to handle like this if I decide to go to Vietnam with a tourist visa again.

### My question

How to find the legal, yet best priced authorized visa on arrival approval letter agency for Vietnam tourist visa?
<sub>Perhaps there is a list somewhere - or a search engine query trick that could help.</sub>

Comment: Why not use an e-visa instead, if you're eligible for one?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vietnam

Comment: @JonathanReez I now saw these are for 30 days only, but I consider coming to Vietnam for longer than that (and also, the citizenship I hold isn't in the list)...

Comment: Always best to apply before and get the VISA before you arrive, I am eligible for VOA but I still handle it before I go just to avoid the massive queues and waiting times and annoyance

Comment: What's the benefit of applying through these agencies versus applying directly?

https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt

Comment: @hojusaram as I have answered to Jonathan, the country of which I hold citizenship isn't allowed for Evisa.

Comment: I couldn't find a list anywhere; the most likely website to have such a list turned out to be a Vietnamese government intranet site that wanted a password I don't have, not being a Vietnamese government official. I will note that the US State Department can't even tell where to find a list of legitimate agencies, and they recommend avoiding these agencies entirely and obtaining visas from the consulate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks --- about avoiding these completely --- I am not sure the fees payed in a Vietnam general-consulate office around the globe would be different to me as someone who cannot use e-visa.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's 25 USD at any embassy, or some additional charge for expedited service. Though for some reason they seem to want to hide the fee amount. Interestingly the Vietnamese embassy in Ottawa also has a warning about those visa-on-arrival sites, as does the one in Washington.

Comment: First - you don't *have* to get a VOA approval letter - you could simply apply for a Visa directly from the vietnamese embassy. (which does have the benefit of meaning less queueing on arriva, and can be used at *any* entry point.)

Second, for whatever reason, the Vietnamese government declines to indicate which agencies are approved and which are not. It's literally a gamble applying for these letters.

Comment: @CMaster if you are 100% sure that I shouldn't use these and there is the alternative of going to a local embassy (although I don't live in the country that citizenship of which I hold), than I humbly think it should be an answer which I would gladly bounty and up vote and accept; in my opinion, some resources on which a strict determination is best would be very helpful and will greatly up popular the answer.

Comment: I don't say that you shouldn't - years ago, I travelled to Vietnam with a  pre-approved VoA letter (from the travel agent that was organising the whole trip - fi they were scamming us, we had bigger problems than just entry to the country). But if you want to be *sure* of having valid entry, then a standard paper-in-passport visa is available from Vietnamese embassies - and I don't recall there being any restrictions on residency/nationality.

Comment: @CMaster your approach to this was yet the most helpful --- I hope it's okay I'll just opinion that even if you write an answer about this and although it won't answer the question in session, I will still upvote it and comment that I did so because it's a good helping approach.

Comment: @JohnDoea yeah, I'll try to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Vietnamese government does not publish any list (at least not in any language I understand) of authorised travel agents to issue a pre-approval VoA letter. I can vouch from personal experience that this unusal route of obtaining a letter from a travel agent is legitimate, however there is no way of you knowing if you have received a valid letter until you arrive at the border.

If you wish to travel with more certainty of entering Vietnam, you have two options:

- Get an e-visa from https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/. This is an *actual* Vietnamese government site, that I found via the British FCO linking to it. Note that there are many commerical travel agent sites masquerading as offical government sites.
- Apply for a traditional paper visa from your nearest Vietnamese Embassy. Note that this has the additional advantage that it can be used at *any* entry point, not just certain airports, and may have greater flexibility. Again, the Vietnamese government does not maintain a readily accessible list of the websites for these. I suggest you find their contact details via the local government where you are. To the best of my knowledge, the Vietnam does not care about citizenship in relation to which embassy you apply to.